# Django : Inheritance error- TemplateSyntaxError at / “Could not pass the remainder”

Tags: python, html, django, inheritance

I have a website running using Django that uses the following dgango blocktag to render text within a base.html file.

```
      {% block content %}
      <h1>Welcome </h1>
      <p1> This is the site template </p1>
      {% endblock content %}
```

However, to describe a page content and not the site itself, I have the following page.html which is meant to inherit the code from base.html

```
       {% extends “base.html” %}
       {% block content %}
       <h1>Greetings</h1>
       <p>The_page_template</p>
        {% endblock content %}
```

Changing views.py from render base.html to render page.html as follows causes the error.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):

    #return render(request, "base.html")          // this works
    return render(request, 'pages/page.html')     // this does not
```

The uploaded image is a screenshot of the broken webpage. The best explanation I can offer is that there is an error in the spacing of the code or the pathing to page.html. With pathing I do notice the broken webpage does point to page.html. The following is a relevant statement from settings.py

```
‘DIRS’: [BASE_DIR / ‘site/templates’]
'APP_DIRS' : TRUE
```

[image]

For the sake of completeness, the following paths are described.

```
root/site/templates/base.html
root/pages/templates/pages/page.html
root/pages/views.py
root/site/settings.py
```

Any help appreciated in resolving this error - thanks

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/6562458)

Comment: change ```{% extends “base.html” %}``` to ```{% extends "base.html" %}``` you put the wrong ```"```

Comment: You're typing curly quotes `”`. Always use straight quotes `"`. It happens when you copy the code from online articles which also have curly quote characters in the html.

Comment: Interesting - thanks. The " moves from straight to curly as I type in notepad.There must be a way to fix this !

Comment: make sure block content and endblock content tag must be in both the templates